# combining head and tail methods in R

Tags: r, dataframe, tail, head, cat

I use the head(d) and tail(d) methods in R package utils a lot - frequently one after the other. So I wrote a simple wrapper for the two functions:

```r
    ht <- function(d, m=5, n=m){
      # print the head and tail together
      cat(" head -->  ", head(d,m), "\n", "--------", "\n", "tail -->  ", tail(d,n), "\n")
    }
```

And I got some unexpected results. Can someone please help me understand why? (so i can fix it or at least understand your solution!).

Some background...

Numeric values work fine:

```
x <- 1:100
ht(x)
```

So does complex:

```
ni <- as.complex(1:100)
ht(ni)
```

and characters:

```
ll <- letters[1:26]
ht(ll)
```

Matrix loses it's structure, returning [1,1] to [5,5] + [16,1] to [20,5] but as two vectors -- compare:

```
m <- matrix(1:10, 20)
ht(m)
```

to:

```
head(m, 5)
tail(m,5)
```

I would like to keep the matrix structure, as the utils methods does - is this possible?

Finally (well, there may be more bugs, this is just where I'm up to) data.frames are a mess:

```
df <- data.frame(num=x[1:26], char=ll)
ht(df)
```

This yields the following error:

```
head -->   Error in cat(list(...), file, sep, fill, labels, append) :   
  argument 2 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'
```

Steps so far:

As the utils method keeps the matrix tidy when done in bits, I tried to fix the problem with the following edit:

```
function(d, m=5, n=m){
  # print the head and tail together
  rb <- rbind(head(d, m), tail(d,n))
  if (class(d) == 'matrix'){
    len <- nrow(rb)
    cat(" head -->  ", rb[(1:m),], "\n", "--------", "\n", "tail -->  ", rb[((len-n):len),], "\n")
  }
  else cat(" head -->  ", rb[1,], "\n", "--------", "\n", "tail -->  ", rb[2,], "\n")
}
```

Which does not seem to have done anything to the matrix and still breaks with the same error when I use:

```
ht(df)
```

I am guessing from the errors that there is some issue with cat() here, but I cannot figure out what it is or how to fix it.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: In your R console, when you type `head(m, 5)`, it is showing you the same result as would `print(head(m, 5))`. So consider using `print` instead of `cat` if that's how you want your result to look like.

Comment: flodel's is the answer. Intermix your cat functions that output annotation with print functions to show the objects. @flodel, put that as an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not modify your function to output a list instead?

```
ht <- function(d, m=5, n=m){
  # print the head and tail together
  list(HEAD = head(d,m), TAIL = tail(d,n))
}
```

Here's the output for your `matrix` and `data.frame`:

```
ht(matrix(1:10, 20))
# $HEAD
#      [,1]
# [1,]    1
# [2,]    2
# [3,]    3
# [4,]    4
# [5,]    5
# 
# $TAIL
#       [,1]
# [16,]    6
# [17,]    7
# [18,]    8
# [19,]    9
# [20,]   10

ht(data.frame(num=x[1:26], char=ll))
# $HEAD
#   num char
# 1   1    a
# 2   2    b
# 3   3    c
# 4   4    d
# 5   5    e
# 
# $TAIL
#    num char
# 22  22    v
# 23  23    w
# 24  24    x
# 25  25    y
# 26  26    z
```

Comment: No reason not to - i just hadn't realised it was necessary. In the case that ncols is 1 do you think it is best to unclass and treat as a vector? Or best to keep the list form?

Comment: @ricardo, what are you planning to do with the output? Is it being used interactively to just get some information about your data? Are you saving the output? Generally, though, I would say that if you want an accurate representation of your data, just keep it in the list form.

Comment: i was just planning on using it at the terminal - and i was keen to use cat only as therefore it would return a NULL ... so i could not get into trouble with assignment if i 'forgot'.

Comment: mrdwab, after some experimentation, i decided that a return value was not the worst thing in the world ... it could well be useful.  I've amended you code so that the output relates to the inputs, so one can see what's gone on if you 'forget'. i think that solves my concern. Thus, it is now: function(d, m=5, n=m){
  # print the head and tail together
  list <- NULL
  list[[paste0('HEAD #', m)]] <- head(d,m)
  list[[paste0('TAIL #', n)]] <- tail(d,n)
  return(list)
}

Comment: +1. @mrdwab: i went with your solution - i've cribbed it for a blog post [here](http://ricardianambivalence.com/2012/07/28/creating-an-r-package-in-10-mins/). I linked back to this answer - just FYI.

Answer (score 5):

It was suggested I turn my comment into an answer.

In your R console, when you type `head(m, 5)`, what you see printed on your screen is really the result of `print(head(m, 5))`. So if this is what you want your output to look like, consider using the `print` function rather than `cat` when displaying the `head` and `tail` of your objects:

```
ht <- function(d, m=5, n=m) {
  # print the head and tail together
  cat("head -->\n")
  print(head(d,m))
  cat("--------\n")
  cat("tail -->\n")
  print(tail(d,n))
}

m <- matrix(1:10, 20)
ht(m)
# head -->
#      [,1]
# [1,]    1
# [2,]    2
# [3,]    3
# [4,]    4
# [5,]    5
# --------
# tail -->
#       [,1]
# [16,]    6
# [17,]    7
# [18,]    8
# [19,]    9
# [20,]   10
```

I find @mrdwab's answer to be a very elegant solution. It does not explicitly use `print`, instead returns a list. However, when his function is called from the R console and the output is not assigned to anything, then it is printed to the console (hence `print` is used implicitly). I hope that helps you understand what's going on.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. I note that head and tail in utils have methods for ftable, table and function - will this approach handle all these cases also? (i am afk, so cannot check just now - but wanted to comment to say thankyou for explaining).

Comment: Yes, anything for which there are both `head` and `tail` methods.

Answer (score 2):

If you're already coding using the `tidyverse` principles and use the `%>%` (pipe) operator it is actually very easy to have just a one-liner:

```
library(magrittr)

your_dataframe %>% {
    rbind( head(., 8), tail(., 8) )
    } %>%
    nrow()

# [1] 16
```

That basically uses `rbind` to merge the top `head()` and bottom `tail()` of the `your_dataframe`. The `{}` are used for calling lambda expressions (more info [here](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/pipe.html)). The `.` inside the `head` and `tail` means "Standard input" (`your_dataframe`).

If you are using `R` version >= 4.1.0, you can benefit from the native pipe operator `|>` so that the code above would be written as:

```
your_dataframe |> (\(x) {
    rbind( head(x, 8), tail(x, 8) )
    })() |> 
    nrow()
# [1] 16
```

Please note that the first parenthesis of `(\(x)` is closed after the  second `})` and this chunk of code behaves like a function so it has `()` afterwards.