# Change index when printing vectors

Tags: r, pretty-print, tail

I would like to make a function for R than shows both the [head and tail as asked and answered in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600391/combining-head-and-tail-methods-in-r). The solution to that question basically suggests a version like this (slightly modified) which works fine.

```
ht <- function(x, n = 6L, m=n, returnList=FALSE, ...) {

    if (!returnList) {
        print(head(x, n, ...))
        cat("...\n")
        print(tail(x, m, ...))
        invisible(NULL)
    }   
    else {
        list(head = head(x, n, ...), tail = tail(x,m, ...))
    }
}
```

It works fine with data frames

```
> ht(trees, 3)
  Girth Height Volume
1   8.3     70   10.3
2   8.6     65   10.3
3   8.8     63   10.2
...
   Girth Height Volume
29  18.0     80   51.5
30  18.0     80   51.0
31  20.6     87   77.0
```

and matrices

```
> ht(diag(10), 3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[2,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[3,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
...
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[8,]     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     0
[9,]     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1     0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     1
```

and vectors

```
> ht(1:10, 3)
[1] 1 2 3
...
[1]  8  9 10
```

However, I don't like the way the output looks for vectors. There are two problems which are shown in the example above:

1. The spacing between the numbers differ because the tail end includes '10' which has two digits while the head end only contains one-digit numbers.
2. The index for the tail end starts at [1] but I'd like it to start at [8].

So I'd love the output (for vectors) to look like this

```
> ht(1:10, 3)
[1]  1  2  3
...
[8]  8  9 10
```

The first question can probably be fixed by a wee bit of bookkeeping on the extracted vectors. Potentially tedious but doable. However, I cannot see how I can solve my second question without recreating the output completely myself. `tail()` returns a vector, so it is not surprising that `tail(1:10,3)`s index starts at 1, since the vector `c(8, 9, 10)` is passed on to `print.default()`.

Now, the tail output could be started with something like the following but that messes up the spacing and results in all sorts of problems if the line becomes too long, since it doesn't wrap in the same pretty way that `print.default()` ensures.

```
ht2 <- function(x, n = 6L, m=n, returnList=FALSE, ...) {    
    start <- length(x)-n+1
    cat("[", start,"] ", paste0(tail(x, m), sep=" "), sep="")
}
```

Any good alternatives/ideas would be appreciated

Comment: It doesn't seem like there's anything special about vectors for the spacing issue... if `ht(1:10, 3)` bugs you, why not `ht(matrix(1:(5*1000), ncol = 5, byrow = T), 3)`?

Comment: @Gregor Yeah that bugs me too. But I guessed I could fix that for various special cases if I could handle the vector situation